# 3.5mm Audio Female to Dual Female?

Tags: audio, adapter, 3.5mm

I've been trying to look online for a 3.5 female to dual female adapter and I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Does it exist?

What I want to be able to do is have the output from my laptop and the output from my tv to go to my speakers. Is it possible to combine streams like that? If not, is there something that is maybe like a switch?

Thanks a bunch,
Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply use a splitter to hook up two audio sources to your speakers, you could damage something.

But as you suspected, you can [buy a switch](http://electronicsusa.com/mk1and2.html) which will let you hook up both audio sources to a single output device.

Or, if you're more of a DIYer, you could [build it yourself](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Construct-a-35mm-Switch-diy/).

Comment: In fact you do not get more garbage than listening to two separate speakers attached to TV and laptop. But you are right about the risk of damaging the outputs.

Comment: @GurkenPapst I tried using a splitter this way years ago and thought I remembered hearing some pretty awful sounds, but I'll take your word for it. Thanks.

Comment: OK, you will indeed get a poor frequency response and/or more or less additional distortion if you abuse a splitter for this purpose. I thought you meant combining signals would be not useful at all.

Answer (score 1):

While I am not aware of any ready-made adapters for this purpose, it is possible in general. There is only one problem: In audio systems output impedance is way lower than input impedance. Directly connecting two outputs puts high load on them, so the amplifiers might get damaged and at least the power on the input will be very low. Putting two series resistors (try 5k) in the signal paths before joining them fixes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

No , but getting a female to female should be easy enough, then putting that on either a male to Y adapted 2 female should be easy enough.

we play this game at RadioShack Called "Make that adaption" :-)  Whoever can make the adaption in the least ammount of connections wins. Eventually i just cut a wire, and put my own end connection on.

But let me show you what I am referring to.
http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2103870 <-- stereo Y wire, A wire because it does not stick out very far like...
http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2102527 <-- stereo Y Adapter.
then
http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2102697 <-- female female adapter

Just examples. and crashing 2 analog signals to the same speakers, is possible, if they are both line level, but you can have many possible problems with that, so you will have to test for yourself.

A ground loop isolation http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2062214 <-- 1:1 transformer with rca jacks , can come in handly when getting signals between devices, would also have to be adapted to Again , but we can make that adaption in 3 :-)
http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2103225

They do have atenuated connections and atenuation adapters pre-built, which might become more nessisary with Headphone outs on laptops, which can have high output levels. http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2103841  <-- some kind of MONO resistered 1/8 wire (not good).
 But like Gurken Papst pointed out, it is just a 10c resister tossed in there. It is often better to put your own in, so you can change it up or down appropriate for the levels.

Radioshack was just the source for pictures, you should be able to get that stuff online anywhere.

Comment: Splitting one output into two inputs will work this way, but not two outputs into one input. See explanation in my answer why there is a risk and signal level will be really low if you would try it nevertheless.

Comment: yup, I covered the non line level in my answer Later, anything else is not going to break an amp, unless the amp is pure junk. depending on the curcuits at both ends they might not mix well.  Look at the costs of the stupid wires, for $29 you can get a cheap Mixer :-)